# Unable to step over property evaluation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging

My problem has started since a few days back, before that everything was working fine. There was no major change made.

Following is the code sample :

```
result = GetTestPlanResultDetails(filter, resultId, config);
```

and here is the filter class :

```
    public class DashboardFilter
{
    public DashboardFilter();

    public short[] RiskLevels
    {
        get
        {
            return this.riskLevels.Split(',').Select(short.Parse).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            this.riskLevels = string.Join(",", value);
        }
    }

    public short[] TestMethods
    {
        get
        {
            return this.testMethods.Split(',').Select(short.Parse).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            this.testMethods = string.Join(",", value);
        }
    }

    public string riskLevels { get; set; }

    public string testMethods { get; set; }

    public bool includeRetests { get; set; }
}
```

Issue here is that whenever I wish to step inside the function with F11, it steps in the RiskLevels property evaluation which is inside DashboardFilter class. I have already enabled "Step over properties and operators" in dubug setting.

Whenever I pass 'NULL' as filter then the step in works. But while using the DashboardFilter class object it always evaluates the property and never goes inside the function that I want to debug. Please help!!

Comment: Is your application using multiple threads?

Comment: Not particularly, it is just a simple web app which accesses services hosted on a same machine and displays on web page. I think the issue here isn't because of threads. As I've said when I pass 'NULL' value as filter then I am able to step into the desired function. I don't really know why debugger is pushing me inside a property even though I've disabled the option for the same.

Comment: That property shouldn't even be evaluated at the line you've posted. Do you have "Require source files to exactly match the original version" enabled?

Comment: Yes yes,  I have enabled that option. I think at this point thatbl it's a bug... Or maybe installing and uninstalling resharper caused this,  but I also tried reinstalling VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get over this issue by manually attaching debugger to the process 'w3wp.exe'.

Earlier the Visual Studio automatically attached the debugger to the process if I try to step inside it using F11, but recently this behavior is not taking place.